# Best way to find out the object type of each item in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the best way to find out the object type of each item in a list?

I have been using the below but it is very cumbersome and requires that one knows of the object type in order to be able to test for it.

```
for form in form_list:

    if type(form) is list:
        print 'it is a list'
    else:
        print 'it is not a list'

    if type(form) is dict:
        print 'it is a dict'
    else:
        print 'it is not a dict'              

    if type(form) is tuple:
        print 'it is a tuple'
    else:
        print 'it is not a tuple' 

    if type(form) is str:
        print 'it is a string'
    else:
        print 'it is not a string'             

    if type(form) is int:
        print 'it is an int'
    else:
        print 'it is not an int'
```

Comment: `print map(type, form_list)`? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2.7:

```
form_list = ['blah', 12, [], {}, 'yeah!']
print map(type, form_list)
```

> `[str, int, list, dict, str]`

In Python 3.4:

```
form_list = ['blah', 12, [], {}, 'yeah!']
print(list(map(type, form_list)))
```

> `[<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'list'>, <class 'dict'>, <class 'str'>]`

Comment: It would have been simpler to just add a `list()` call in the Python 3 case.

Comment: @BlackJack Duh. I knew I was overcomplicating things; totally forgot about ``list()``. I guess I got carried away with trying to take advantage of argument unpacking since ``print()`` is a function in Python 3. Anyway thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 1):

Knowing type in python is oftentimes not the desired way to go. Read up on the topic `duck-typing` if you're new to this.

If you still want to go down this path, do:

```
objtype = type(form)
if objtype is list:
    #do stuff
elif objtype is str:
    #do other stuff
else:
    #can't handle this
```

and so on

Comment: If it is really necessary to check for a type and act on that information I would prefer `isinstance()` to at least also act on subtypes and not only the _exact_ type.